# Mass reprojection of raster files in a loop [Linux]

Tags: python, gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, bash

I have a folder with numerous `.asc` raster files that each accompanied by a corresponding `.prj` file. The file basename is the same for both files. The projection however can vary between all of them (they are currently in various different UTM projection).
What I want to achieve is to standardize the projection of all those individual raster files.
My current approach is this `bash`-script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Starting Conversion to WGS84
for f in *.asc;
 do 
  echo Converting "$f";
  echo To "${f%.asc}_wgs84.tif";
  gdalwarp "$f" "${f%.asc}_wgs84.tif" -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84";
  done
echo Conversion finished
```

However the script fails for each file returning:

> "Invalid request to pj_param, fatal"

So I would like to see a bunch of reprojected .tif (or any other format) files that all have the same projection.

While typing this I am also working on a `python` script, which however does not seem to be as straight-forward as `bash`.

---

call: `gdalinfo grid2000.asc`
It seems to fail even at the end?

```
Driver: AAIGrid/Arc/Info ASCII Grid
Files: grid2000.asc
       grid2000.prj
Size is 16, 16
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_30N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Origin = (565146.201264380943030,680158.854243048001081)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
invalid request to pj_param, fatal
```

call:
gdalsrsinfo xyz.prj # (Note that xyz.prj could be a different file)

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=utm +zone=17 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_17S",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-81],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Comment: try -t_srs epsg:4326

Comment: So like this? `gdalwarp "$f" "${f%.asc}_wgs84.tif" -t_srs "epsg:4326";` That sadly fails too. My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the projection information is not saved within the .asc itself but instead in a seperate .prj file.

Comment: no quotes around epsg:4326 -  can you post one of the .prj files?

Comment: actually what happens if you run gdalinfo on one of the .asc files? does it pick up the projection?

Comment: Edited. Very strange. The error even pops up in the gdalinfo screen

Comment: You can force to use the .prj file by adding `-s_srs xyz.prj`. Does gdalsrsinfo understand the .prj file?

Comment: I am using the following call `gdalwarp "$f" "${f%.asc}_wgs84.tif" -s_srs "${f%.prj}" -t_srs EPSG:4326;` now and it returns `"ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:"` . Yes, it does! Edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before running your script in my Debian system:

[image]

It ran perfectly without any error (and without modifications anywhere):

[image]

Each image was adequately projected to WGS84.

What is the result of one individual projection with the command at the bash console (without script)? Is it successfully?

Comment: Thanks for testing! This gives me confidence that this issue might be related to sth. happening on my system. I am running this on an external server where I don't have any admin-rights and I am smelling some faulty configuration here....

Comment: OK. I thought in a GDAL problem because your script works perfectly.